# DataSourceTransactionManager not persisting data

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring data JPA to insert/update some data in an Oracle database. If I dont explicitly specify a `dataSource` and/or a `platformTransactionManager`, everything works great and I am able to insert/update data. If I specify `DataSourceTransactionManager` as the `platformTransactionManager` then no exceptions are thrown but the data is not inserted in the databse.

It seems like a commit issue. Using this datasource seems to require an explicit commit which is not happening and because of the that, the data is never actually persisted. I have tried specifying the `spring.datasource.tomcat.defaultAutoCommit: true` but it didnt help.

Any ideas on how I can commit on completion of every transaction. My insert/update code looks like this

```
@Transactional
@Override
public OrderEntity save(OrderResponse order) {
    OrderEntity o = orderRepository.unwrap(order);
    return orderRepository.save(o);
}
```

transaction manager bean:

```
@Primary
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager txManager(DataSource dataSource) {
    return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}
```

--

Here is a sample project that demonstrates the issue. I am using h2 here and by simply adding the `transactionManager`, data is not persisted anymore

[sample project](https://github.com/adeelmahmood/oracle-commit)

Comment: I guess you do use `@EnableTransactionManagement`, right?

Comment: Yes, I've that in a configuration class

Comment: I have added a sample project that shows the problem even with an H2 database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was fixed by using `jpaTransactionManager` because I think in this case, the `dataSourceTransactionManager` was not tied to the `entityManager` being used by JPA